# Why does a generic UWP app show an error?

Tags: debugging, uwp, windows-runtime

I created a simple UWP app from the VS 2017 blank UWP template. No added XAML or C# code-behind:

1. Create new app with Blank Universal Windows template
2. Set Debugger type to Mixed (Managed and Native)
3. Build and Run (No XAML or code added)
4. Following error: WinRT originate error - 0x80070490 : 'Element not found.'

This happens every time. Does anyone have a handle on this error? If I don't have Mixed Mode debugging on, I don't see the error but I'm assuming it's still there. Is this an error that I should be concerned about?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

A lot of problem may result this error, and it should not be a fatal error in your case. Most likely you changed the default Exception Settings in visual studio.
Just like all other apps, Windows use exceptions and catch them at different level.
For end user, you should not see this exception and app should not crash.

In your situation, I think you click continue and the program should not crash, and it should not be a big concern.

I suggest you:
1, start and debug your app, open Debug|Windows|Exception Setting, then click the 'restore the list to default settings' button
2, restart your app.
3, You should not catch the exception, but you still see error message in Output window.

If you still see a exception window popup, you need to post more information like your os version, and then someone can help you

Comment: Thank you, Canhua Li, I will get back to this work item next week and do what you have suggested. It seems to make sense.

Answer (score 0):

I met this error when I call the winRT api  `CommunityToolkit.WinUI.Notifications.ToastNotificationHistoryCompat.Clear()`. Then let the app toast someting once the error had gone.